# Cucumber+ WebStorm plugin not detecting any e2e tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, cucumber, webstorm

I'm trying to set up [Cucumber +](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16289-cucumber-) plugin on WebStorm (IntelliJ) and no Cucumber tests are being detected.

Folder structure:

```
- UI
  - Project1
    - e2e (cucumber)
  - Project2
    - e2e (cucumber)
```

What I'm seeing:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest submitting a ticket to the plugin vendor, https://github.com/maximehamm/tzatziki/issues